# Motorcycle "melting" S2 bulbs

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, headlight, bulbs

My motorcycle (Keeway Superlight 125) has been burning headlight bulbs (S2, BA20d bayonet) at an impressive rate (one every a few months). By inspecting the bulbs I noticed that the little "reflector" inside (the piece of metal that shields the low beam filament) is noticeably warped like it's been overheated.

Voltage at the bulb with the engine running at about 6000 RPM is 12.70 V (+- 0.05 V) and seems pretty stable at varying engine speed.

I thought it could be caused by a poorly designed headlight reflector focusing light back on the bulb but the little "reflector" inside the bulb becomes red hot also when it's not placed inside the headlight.

[Warped reflector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIoTY.jpg)

[Here the reflector does not seem warped but it fell off breaking both filaments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR5gi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you've replaced the bulbs, do you touch the bulb with your bare hand? Getting even traces of oil from your fingers can cause the bulbs to die prematurely.